# Customize Title column with JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, json-formatting, json

Currently my Title column has a link in it, but I need to make it bigger and change the font **while** keeping the href function (after clicking on the title it opens editing).

When I use `"elmType": "a"`, the text disappears.

I found following script, but it does not work:

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column- 
formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "a",
"txtContent": "@currentField.desc",
"style": {
  "font-size": "13pt"
},
"attributes": {
  "href": "@currentField"
}
}
```

Anyone got a hint?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below JSON to update the Title field.

Updated the JSON to open Edit Form on Title column value click.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "editProps"
  },
  "style": {
    "border": "none",
    "background-color": "transparent",
    "font-size": "13pt",
    "text-decoration":"underline"
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

Other References:

1. [Column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)
2. [Samples on GitHub](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples)
3. [Open Edit Form using JSON Formatting](https://ericgregorich.com/use-json-to-add-a-clickable-button-to-a-modern-sharepoint-list-view/)

[image]

Comment: After I use this JSON, the text disappears. There is not exactly https link, but after clicking the title, there is a dialogue window with editing the item.

Comment: So, on the click on Title column value you want to open Edit Form?

Comment: Yes. When I click on Title, I should be able to edit all values in an item.

Comment: @MartinOak check the updated answer. It opens the Edit item pane when user click on the title

Comment: Thats it! Thank you so much.